# cannot convert boost::lambda::placeholder1_type

Tags: c++, boost, boost-lambda

I am trying to play with boost::lambda, but I bumped on an error I cannot figure out how to solve.

I have the feeling this is a beginner error, so please excuse my ignorance (and, I have to admit, my laziness for not reading the whole boost lamda documentation too).

It seems that in some cases using boost::bind (or maybe boost::lambda::bind?), is better suited than boost::lambda, but I am not sure if it can be applied here. I would like not having to write a separate function for `if cond(arg1) arg2.insert(arg1) ;`, as it would defeat the purpose; it would not be much better than a functor I guess.

I am using boost 1.35 with VC9 at work. The errors are at the `cond()` and `insert()` calling sites:
"C2664: cannot convert parameter 1 from 'boost::lambda::placeholder1_type"

I replicated the problem with this snippet with g++ on my cygwin.

```
#include <boost/function.hpp>
#include <boost/lambda/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/lambda/if.hpp>

#include <boost/foreach.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

void work(  boost::function<void(long)> doAction ) {
    long results[] = { 2, 5, 4 };
    BOOST_FOREACH( long r, results )
        doAction( r );
}

bool cond( long r ) { return r % 2 == 0 ; }

int main() {
    using namespace boost::lambda;
    std::set<long> myResults;
    work( 
        if_then( cond(_1) , boost::ref(myResults).get().insert(_1) ) );

    BOOST_FOREACH( long r, myResults )
        std::cout << r << "\n";
}
```

g++ errors:

```
lambda_test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
lambda_test.cpp:21:19: error: cannot convert ‘boost::lambda::placeholder1_type {aka const boost::lambda::lambda_functor<boost::lambda::placeholder<1> >}’ to ‘long int’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘bool cond(long int)’
if_then( cond(_1) , boost::ref(myResults).get().insert(_1) ) );
               ^
lambda_test.cpp:21:60: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::set<long int>::insert(boost::lambda::placeholder1_type&)’
if_then( cond(_1) , boost::ref(myResults).get().insert(_1) ) );
```

Any help would be appreciated,

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mixing deferred execution with immediate evaluation:

```
boost::ref(myResults).get().insert(_1)
```

Here, `boost::ref(myResults)` is not lazy, so `.get()` isn't either. The type of `boost::ref(myResults).get()` is *just* `std::set<long> &`, and that type's `insert` member function doesn't have an overload that takes a Boost Lambda placeholder.

I'm not well-versed in Boost Lambda (anymore) because I've moved to it's successor library, Boost Phoenix. Here's a 1-to-1 translation with fixes: **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a3fef10a60bbda7c)**

```
#include <boost/phoenix.hpp>

#include <boost/foreach.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

template <typename Action>
void work(  Action doAction ) {
    long results[] = { 2, 5, 4 };
    BOOST_FOREACH( long r, results )
        doAction( r );
}

bool cond( long r ) { return r % 2 == 0 ; }


int main() {
    namespace phx = boost::phoenix;
    using namespace phx::placeholders;

    std::set<long> myResults;
    work( 
        if_(phx::bind(cond, _1)) [ phx::insert(phx::ref(myResults), _1) ] );

    BOOST_FOREACH( long r, myResults )
        std::cout << r << "\n";
}
```

Prints

```
2
4
```

I'd suggest to look at Phoenix function adaptation, to avoid the bind expressions:

- http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/phoenix/doc/html/phoenix/modules/function/adapting_functions.html

Comment: Thanks for your promptness! Unfortunately I cannot update our boost version and boost::phoenix is not in 1.35 (there is a boost/spirit/phoenix.hpp however). May I ask you how I should fix the same code with boost 1.35 features?
Another point, I do not understand my mixing of deferred execution with immediate evaluation. As there are placeholders how can it evaluate immediately? It is not related to [lambda variables delay](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/doc/html/lambda/le_in_details.html#lambda.delaying_constants_and_variables) is it?

Comment: You can probably use the same code with `#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>` (optionally `phoenix_statement.hpp` as well). BOOST_PHOENIX_ADAPT_FUNCTION will not be available then

Comment: @unagi Regarding the "mixing up", I extended my explanation in the answer. I forgot about that before.

Comment: Oops, I made a mistake boost/spirit/phoenix is folder, no phoenix.hpp. I included all headers of this folder, but `‘phoenix’ is not a namespace-name`. Trying boost::spirit::phoenix was unsuccesful too. I am searching more, and will tell you if I can make it. Thanks

Comment: @unagi I think [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7f5a76fa458c65b7) should work, but it is really awful, maybe sehe will know a way to make it more "palatable". (Adding the link makes it more useful :)). PS: [This](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ecfe74d71f3e830f) is better.

Comment: Oh my god! your first example is… scaring. The second looks more usable in real life but I am looking for a “self-contained” lambda solution.
It would be a pity if it is not possible

Comment: I am going to accept this as an answer, as I guess the real solution is: update boost! cv_and_he also provided a nice snippet. Thank you to you two.